# How to mock test POST requests with body as JSON using ring mock request?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, mocking, ring, http-kit

I am using http-kit as the server with `wrap-json-body` from `ring.middleware.json` to get the stringified JSON content sent from the client as the request body. My `core.clj` is:

```
; core.clj
; .. 
(defroutes app-routes
    (POST "/sign" {body :body} (sign body)))

(def app (site #'app-routes))

(defn -main []
    (-> app
        (wrap-reload)
        (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})
        (run-server {:port 8080}))
    (println "Server started."))
```

When I run the server using `lein run` the method works correctly. I am stringifying the JSON and sending it from the client. The sign method gets the json correctly as `{"abc": 1}`.

The problem is when during mock test. The `sig`n method gets a `ByteArrayInputStream` and I am using `json/generate-string` to convert to string which fails in this case. I tried wrapping the handler in `wrap-json-body` but it is not work. Here are my test cases I tried out `core_test.clj`:

```
; core_test.clj
; ..
(deftest create-sign-test
    (testing "POST sign"
        (let [response
          (wrap-json-body (core/app (mock/request :post "/sign" "{\"username\": \"jane\"}"))
            {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})]
            (is (= (:status response) 200))
            (println response))))

(deftest create-sign-test1
    (testing "POST sign1"
        (let [response (core/app (mock/request :post "/sign" "{\"username\": \"jane\"}"))]
            (is (= (:status response) 200))
            (println response))))

(deftest create-sign-test2
    (testing "POST sign2"
        (let [response (core/app (-> (mock/body (mock/request :post "/sign")
                                       (json/generate-string {:user 1}))
                                     (mock/content-type "application/json")))]
            (is (= (:status response) 200))
            (println response))))

(deftest create-sign-test3
(testing "POST sign3"
    (let [response
      (wrap-json-body (core/app (mock/request :post "/sign" {:headers {"content-type" "application/json"}
                  :body "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}))
        {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})]
        (is (= (:status response) 200))
        (println response))))
```

All of the fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Cannot JSON encode object of class: class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4db77402
```

How can I pass a JSON string as the body to the method in ring mock test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues in your code.

1. Your test doesn't wrap your app handler in `wrap-json-body` so it might not get correctly parsed request body in your handler. You need to first wrap your `app` in `wrap-json-body` and then call it with your mock request. (You could also have your `app` handler to be already wrapped instead of wrapping it both in your main function and tests)

   ```
   (let [handler (-> app (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})]
     (handler your-mock-request))
   ```
2. Your mock request doesn't include proper content type and your `wrap-json-body` won't parse your request body to JSON. That's why your `sign` function gets `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of parsed JSON. You need to add content type to your mock request:

   ```
   (let [request (-> (mock/request :post "/sign" "{\"username\": \"jane\"}")
                     (mock/content-type "application/json"))]
     (handler request))
   ```
3. Verify that your `sign` function returns a response map with JSON as string in body. If it creates response body as input stream you need to parse it in your test function. Below I am using `cheshire` to parse it (converting JSON keys to keywords):

   ```
   (cheshire.core/parse-stream (-> response :body clojure.java.io/reader) keyword)
   ```

Additionally instead of writing your JSON request body by hand you can use Cheshire to encode your data into JSON string:

```
(let [json-body (cheshire.core/generate-string {:username "jane"})]
  ...)
```

With those changes it should work correctly like in my slightly modified example:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (POST "/echo" {body :body}
    {:status 200 :body body}))

(def app (site #'app-routes))

(let [handler (-> app (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true}))
      json-body (json/generate-string {:username "jane"})
      request (-> (mock/request :post "/echo" json-body)
                  (mock/content-type "application/json"))
      response (handler request)]
  (is (= (:status response) 200))
  (is (= (:body response) {:username "jane"})))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The `sign` method is getting the JSON correctly. I have been trying for hours to get this right.